# How do i multiply a a sculpt around its own axis?

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting, sculpt

I am extremely new to Blender and I'm trying to learn how to freehand sculpt using my tablet. I'm a 2D artist trying out 3D.

I'm trying to make a single sculpt of a face and then rotate it around itself much like this

[image]

If anyone could perhaps explain very basic as I'm very unfamiliar with the program.

Comment: I'm no sculptor, but while you're waiting for an answer, you could look up 'Blender Sculpting Radial Symmetry', or suchlike..